Help with relative clause questions?
I have two sentences:
A) I love this chair, which my father bought last year
B) My city has a lot of beautiful places, which makes it a popular travel destination
Here are some questions. Can anyone answer?

Are the clauses starting with "which" in the two sentences above, relative clauses?
In sentence A, is it okay if I change, "which" to "that"? Because as I understand, sentence A uses nonrestrictive relative clause. If I use "that" instead of, "which", it will be a restrictive clause, so it sounds odd to me because "this" seems kinda "restrictive" already?
In sentence B, if I change "which makes" to "making", is the clause "making it a ....." still a relative clause? Also, is the comma setting off the nonrestrictive clause a part of it with the only purpose of separating the clauses?


That this restricts it to one chair only is unrelated to the following nonrestrictive clause.

One question at a time, please, Quốc Anh Phạm. (1A) is more suited to ELL; (1B) has been covered before, for instance at Which-clause functioning adverbially: 'My son chews with his mouth open, which aggravates me.'. The participial clause in (3) is covered at What are the grammatical concepts of this? 'The car ... requires lots of gasoline, making it expensive to operate.'

(2) The that/which problem is addressed at When to use 'that' and when to use 'which' especially in relative clauses. The comma usage is discussed at Does removing the comma before 'which' etc in a non-restrictive clause change the meaning?

@EdwinAshworth Native speakers are less likely, not more likely to recognise a relative clause than a language learner.

@Araucaria - Him I think it's taken for granted now that anyone is welcome to ask a more basic question (hardly suitable for 'linguists / serious English language soeakers') on ELL. I gathered that the primary aim of ELL when set up was to handle more basic questions. Certainly there used to be a 'too basic' transfer option / CV on ELU. // In any case, perhaps you could suggest to OP a duplicate on ELU where prototypical relative clauses have already been covered. There are bound to be some that haven't been closed.

@EdwinAshworth I don't agree with anything you've said, unfortunately.

@Araucaria [1]  Which-clauses after a NP/DetP being classed as relative clauses having already been covered on ELU? / [2] Not bothering to find a duplicate for 'I love this chair, which my father bought last year' ...
[Is] the clause ... starting with "which" in the ... sentence above [a] relative clause ...? I've found two for other questions. I consider that question too basic for a site 'aimed at linguists and other proficient Anglophones. / [3] ELL being open to non- E-S-L users?  / [4] ELL having been introduced to deal with the more basic requests many may have?  All  problems?


Yes, those clauses are relative clauses, without doubt.

No, it is not possible to change "which" to "that", the reason being that this relative clause being a non-defining relative clause it can't retain its non-defining property if "that" is used. Let's recall that the comma is the mark of a non-defining clause, otherwise called a non-determining clause or non-restrictive clause.
https://academicguides.waldenu.edu/writingcenter/grammar/clauses

No, the clause in which "which makes" is replaced by "making" is not a relative clause. It is a nonfinite clause without subject. However, the nonfinite verb form ("making") is a formal indicator of subordination, just as  the relative pronoun (in this case, "which") is such a formal indicator. The comma is not a part of the clause: it is a sentence element with the purpose of articulating the sentence. It can be considered as a marker of syntax, this being so because the syntax is different when it is absent.



Sorry for question 2, I wrote the question wrong. The question should be if I change ", which" to "that" for sentence A, is it still correct? Also, for question 3, is the nonfinite clause (if "which makes" is changed to "making") a reduced relative clause? Thank you

@QuốcAnhPhạm Part 2 of my answer does concern only your second question, whichever way you phrase it.  // A reduced relative is merely a relative in which the relative pronoun has been omitted, so this concept has nothing to do with nonfinite clauses '(which is what "making…" is).  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_relative_clause // Perhaps the typing '", which"' in your comment is not a mere typing error and  you  think that the esentially American practice of including punctuation marks on the right of a quote within that quote has its counterpart on the left; this is never the case.
